# How to set cipher mode in pyOpenSSL?

Tags: python, openssl, rsa, pyopenssl

I am trying to translate this cli command into python: `openssl genpkey -aes-256-cbc -algorithm RSA -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048 -out my-private-key.pem`

So far, the best option I have found is pyOpenSSL, however, I cannot seem to set the cbc cipher mode. At the moment this is how my code looks:

```
gen_key = OpenSSL.crypto.PKey()

gen_key.generate_key(OpenSSL.crypto.TYPE_RSA, 2048)

OpenSSL.crypto.dump_privatekey(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, gen_key, cipher='aes256', passphrase=b"some_passphrase")
```

This however only specifies the cipher, not its mode. When I try to specify the cipher with `cipher='aes256-cbc'` or `cipher='aescbc256'` I get an invalid cipher name error. I would be extremely grateful if someone could help me setup my aes256 cipher to cbc mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `ciphername` argument, you can use the algorithm names printed out by the command `openssl list -cipher-commands`. There you will see mentioned `aes-256-cbc`, which is the name that you were looking for.

You can use those ciphers in a case insensitive way and most of them listed have aliases that you can use as well. For example if you use `openssl -list -cipher-algorithms`, you will notice

```
aes256 => AES-256-CBC
```

so it turns out you were using CBC mode already.

You can verify this also by feeding the generated PEM into the `openssl asn1parse` command, which starts like this (I added a print statement to the code to print the PEM):

```
$ python dumpkey.py | openssl asn1parse
    0:d=0  hl=4 l=1325 cons: SEQUENCE          
    4:d=1  hl=2 l=  87 cons: SEQUENCE          
    6:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :PBES2
   17:d=2  hl=2 l=  74 cons: SEQUENCE          
   19:d=3  hl=2 l=  41 cons: SEQUENCE          
   21:d=4  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :PBKDF2
   32:d=4  hl=2 l=  28 cons: SEQUENCE          
   34:d=5  hl=2 l=   8 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:DAA5C15B1DB3C8CF
   44:d=5  hl=2 l=   2 prim: INTEGER           :0800
   48:d=5  hl=2 l=  12 cons: SEQUENCE          
   50:d=6  hl=2 l=   8 prim: OBJECT            :hmacWithSHA256
   60:d=6  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL              
   62:d=3  hl=2 l=  29 cons: SEQUENCE          
   64:d=4  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :aes-256-cbc
```

I do not know for sure whether all names mentioned in the `list -cipher-commands` are compatible with `dump_privatekey()` and also not whether that list is exhaustive (barring the aliases).

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed, 'aes-256-cbc' is compatible with dump_privatekey() and the command works now. Thank you for the useful openssl commands as well!